# ESD strap/mat when working on battery powered devices/PCBs

Tags: esd, electrostatic

When the devices you're working on are plugged in an outlet or when you're working on loose components, it makes perfectly sense to ground yourself to the outlet or any other solid ground through a 1MOhm resistor. But if you're working on battery powered electronics, then you're actually putting yourself on a different ground than the electronics you're working on. Or do you pull the battery's negative terminal also to the same ground? I don't think that's a good idea...

Comment: The parts you are working on are sitting on your ESD mat and it is connected to the same place your wrist strap is.

Comment: Well, they're not connected to the same ground. Wrist strap --> outlet, electronics --> battery

Comment: The ESD mat and wrist strap is more about safely dissipating built up charge, not about connecting circuits to make them equipotential.  Although once there is no more charge that does happen.

Answer (score 3):

You have a completely wrong idea about how ESD protection works and why it's set up the way it is.

First of all, "working on device plugged in an outlet" (my god that statement) shall never be done while grounded through ESD protection, it's only done when fully isolated from ground. ESD stands for electrostatic discharge, and refers to stray charge accumulated on (usually) the human body. It can reach up to a few KVe, and it's that spark you sometimes see after walking on a plush carpet and then touching another object - that spark is the charge equalizing between two objects. A lot of electronics is sensitive to this discharge and can be damaged by it. Wrist straps and ESD mats provide a high resistance path to ground to slowly drain this stray charge from your body so that when you reach for that IC chip you don't damage it.

Battery powered or not, all sensitive electronics handling should happen with ESD controls on place.

Comment: Let me rephrase: when I'm working on a PCB that's powered through an outlet (e.g. a battery charger), then I (through my wrist strap) am connected to the same ground as the electronics I'm working on. If I'm working on a PCB that's battery powered the situation is different. If I ground myself with a wrist strap (that's grounded to the ground in the outlet), I'm at a different potential than the "ground" of the PCB I'm working on... How does that work in that case?

Comment: The aim is not to have a common ground with a device, the aim is to slowly discharge accumulated electrostatic charges to earth.